# Give role acess in php?

Tags: php, laravel

Is it right approach to write Laravel PHP code to give a role to hr to view certain column? Because after hosting the website stops automatically and start automatically. Code is working fine..

I am new to PHP, I have no idea if i am going wrong in this code can anyone help me out yrr...

```php
<table class="table table-striped mb-0 dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        @role('company')
        <th>{{__('Employee Name')}}</th>
        @endrole
        @role('hr')
        <th>{{__('Employee Name')}}</th>
        @endrole
        <th>{{__('Designation')}}</th>
        <th>{{__('Promotion Title')}}</th>
        <th>{{__('Promotion Date')}}</th>
        <th>{{__('Description')}}</th>
        @if(Gate::check('Edit Promotion') || Gate::check('Delete Promotion'))
          <th width="200px">{{__('Action')}}</th>
        @endif
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="font-style">
    @foreach ($promotions as $promotion)
        <tr>
          @role('company')
          <td>{{ !empty($promotion->employee())?$promotion->employee()->name:'' }}</td>
          @endrole
          @role('hr')
          <td>{{ !empty($promotion->employee())?$promotion->employee()->name:'' }}</td>
          @endrole
          <td>{{ !empty($promotion->designation())?$promotion->designation()->name:'' }}</td>
          <td>{{ $promotion->promotion_title }}</td>
          <td>{{  \Auth::user()->dateFormat($promotion->promotion_date) }}</td>
          <td>{{ $promotion->description }}</td>
          @if(Gate::check('Edit Promotion') || Gate::check('Delete Promotion'))
            <td>
              @can('Edit Promotion')
                <a href="#" data-url="{{ URL::to('promotion/'.$promotion->id.'/edit') }}" data-size="lg" data-ajax-popup="true" data-title="{{__('Edit Promotion')}}" class="edit-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="{{__('Edit')}}"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></a>
              @endcan
              @can('Delete Promotion')
                <a href="#" class="delete-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="{{__('Delete')}}" data-confirm="{{__('Are You Sure?').'|'.__('This action can not be undone. Do you want to continue?')}}" data-confirm-yes="document.getElementById('delete-form-{{$promotion->id}}').submit();"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'route' => ['promotion.destroy', $promotion->id],'id'=>'delete-form-'.$promotion->id]) !!}
                {!! Form::close() !!}
              @endif
            </td>
          @endif
        </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: See Documentation (version select on the left): https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/blade-directives

Comment: Okay good! I have made it an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find what you are asking in the documentation here (version select on the left):
https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/basic-usage/blade-directives

```php
@role('hr')
    I am from hr!
@else
    I am not from hr...
@endrole
```

It further reads `@hasrole('hr')` is an alias of `@role('hr')`, so no worries there.

Similarly, the same goes for permissions:

```php
@can('edit articles')
  //
@endcan
```

For more information, see link mentioned above.